# Trigger event when clicking a paticular option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if the following is possible. I would like to fire different events depending upon which option is selected in a dropdown. So far I thought of this but nothing is happening when I select the option

```
$('#strand_id option[value="5"]:selected').on('click', function(){
  console.log('something just happened!!!')

});
```

I don’t think I can use the change method as this will apply the same event no matter what option is selected (unless there is a way?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#strand_id').on('click ', function () {
    if (this.value == 5) console.log('something just happened !! !')
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8whgyaof/)**

Comment: awesome, not sure why i didn’t think of that but thats great, thanks